# How to prevent xsd.exe from creating uncompileable C#

Tags: c#, xsd, xsd.exe

I am currently trying to generate C# code using `xsd.exe` in order to use it with `System.Xml.Serialization`.

The command i am using is the next one:

```
xsd.exe path\to\eExact-XML.xsd /c /namespace:Namespace.Models /o:path\to\Namespace\Models
```

Alas, the generated code is not compileable due to the next generated snippet:

```cs
/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
public object System {
    get {
        return this.systemField;
    }
    set {
        this.systemField = value;
    }
}
```

One of the generated classes contains a property called `System`, which renders the following compiler error within the `XmlElementAttribute`:

```
eExact-XML.cs(25799, 60): [CS0120] An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'GLTransactionLineIntraStat.System'
```

My current solution is to simple remove the culprit from the generated class, but I don't find this an elegant solution.

Is there any way to tell `xsd.exe` to rename certain properties, or leave out parts of the xsd spec?

Comment: Often there is more than one schema for an application and you need to add an include (see : https://www.w3schools.com/xml/el_include.asp).  A schema often has user define optional items and you need a schema for the options.  Adding the include will resolve missing items.

Comment: @jdweng, thanks for your comment. The problem isn't missing items. The problem is that the `System` property hides the `System` namespace, which results in `System.Xml.xxx` to not being found

Comment: Then change System to _System.  So serialization still works and add above object [XmlElement("System")]

Comment: If all else fails you could automate xsd with some .bat file where you would also somehow fix the issue.

Comment: Seeing the same issue. We interface with an external system having a complex set of included/imported xsd files that we generate into classes.  Same as you, a complexType named "System" generates a class named "System", which throws off pretty much every .NET type reference in the generated class.  We have to manually update all .NET type references with a "global::" prefix, which isn't fun.  Modifying the external system's schema is not an option. Did you ever find a way to supply name overrides or at least get the xsd.exe tool to put "global::" in front of .NET type references?

Comment: Actually I ended up implementing what @jdweng suggested and made a note for our other developers, explaining that anytime the schema files get updated to be sure and rename that one complexType to "_System" and update the one element declaration that references it to use "_System" as well.  That's a heck of a lot easier than dorking with the type references in the generated class.  The serialization/deserialization is not affected and all is well.

Comment: Hey @JCDrumKing, I have never found a solution to this problem.
I tackled it the same way you did, with a lot of reluctance, as it felt like "not a real solution"